# Capture external cmd output

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to capture output from an external cmd. The cmd generates a key file. Sample code:

```
$Executable = 'C:\Program Files\Testing\keygen.exe'
$Output = & $Executable "-Args"
echo "Output is: $Output"
```

Output:

```
Using OpenSSL Version OpenSSL ...
Generating new md5 file and link
key.keys-> key_MD5_WIN-3A ...
"Output is: "
```

How can I redirect the output "Using OpenSSL........." to be stored in variable `$Output`? Currently it only outputs to the PowerShell window.

Comment: Take a look at how redirection works with powershell: https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-redirection.html

Comment: `$Output = (& $Executable "-Args")` in case you want to catch **ALL** streams in $Output `$Output = (& $Executable "-Args" *>&1)`